# Filter sub-document array using substring as criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

My collection:

```
{
  title: 'Computers',
  maincategories:[
    {
       title: 'Monitors',
       subcategories:[
         {
            title: '24 inch',
            code: 'AFG'
         }
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want query the code. The code is just the first part so I want to have all subcategories that contains the given search. So `AFG101` would return this subcategories.

My query:

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  var q = {
    'maincategories.subcategories': {
      $elemMatch: {
        code: 'AFG101'
      }
    }
  };

  var query = mongoose.model('TypeCategory').find(q, {'maincategories.$': 1, 'title': 1});

  query.exec((err, docs) => {
    res.status(200).send(docs);
  });
};
```

My problem:

1. How do I search for a part of a string? `AFG101` should return all subcategories with property `code` containing any part of the string. So in this case, `AFG` would be a hit. Same as in this sql question: [MySQL: What is a reverse version of LIKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472063/mysql-what-is-a-reverse-version-of-like)
2. How do I project the subcategories. Current query returns all subcategories. I only want to returns those hitting.

Comment: I guess it would be better if you could parse the code `AFG101` into the corresponding code before querying Mongo.

Comment: @hyades, I don't understand. How can I do this?

Comment: I think I understand what you want in the first ask.

You want, e.g.: to have multiple docs with "code:AFG1,", "code; AFG2", "code:AFG3, "code:ABC1". So, when the user (of whatever) type something like "AFG" mongo will retrieve you all the docs that contain "AFG" in ther CODE field. If so, check "regex" in mongodb.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#examples

Comment: @AlbertoRubio, No, other way around. If the user type AFG101 and the property code in my document has code: AFG, this should be returned.

Comment: Well... it's the same, isn't it? $regex would search the string you type and look for that string into your docs. It's not exactly what you want, but you could start there. Or maybe, if you know all your codes begin with 3 same characters, make and split and get only the "AFG" from the string. First 3 characters of the string. It's all I have, sry.

Comment: I can't see its the same. My input is AFG101. I need AFG returned. I don't see how $regex solves this.

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is in MongoDB 3.4 using the [`$indexOfCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/) string aggregation operator.

```
let code = "afg101";

db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "title": 1, 
        "maincategories": { 
            "$map": { 
                "input": "$maincategories", 
                "as": "mc", 
                "in": { 
                    "$filter": { 
                        "input": "$$mc.subcategories", 
                        "as": "subcat", 
                        "cond": { 
                            "$gt": [ 
                                { 
                                    "$indexOfCP": [ 
                                        code, 
                                        { "$toLower": "$$subcat.code" }
                                     ] 
                                }, 
                               -1 
                            ] 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }} 
])
```

which returns:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582cba57e6f570d40d77b3a8"),
    "title" : "Computers",
    "maincategories" : [
        [
            {
                "title" : "24 inch",
                "code" : "AFG"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

You can read my other answers to similar question [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908100/mongodb-regex-search-on-integer-value/38672272#38672272), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39272469/extracting-a-list-of-substrings-from-mongodb-using-a-regular-expression/39275122#39275122) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832525/most-efficient-way-to-change-a-string-field-value-to-its-substring/38845765#38845765).

---

From 3.2 backward, the only way to do this is with [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/map-reduce/).

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() { 
        var code = 'AFG101'; 
        var maincategories = this.maincategories.map(function(sdoc) {
            return { 
                "title": sdoc.title, 
                "subcategories": sdoc.subcategories.filter(function(scat) { 
                    return code.indexOf(scat.code) != -1; 
                }
            )};
        }); 
        emit(this._id, maincategories); 
   }, 
   function(key, value) {}, 
   { "out": { "inline": 1 } 
})
```

which yields something like this:

```
{

    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("582c9a1aa358615b6352c45a"),
            "value" : [
                {
                    "title" : "Monitors",
                    "subcategories" : [
                        {
                            "title" : "24 inch",
                            "code" : "AFG"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 15,
        "counts" : {
            "input" : 1,
            "emit" : 1,
            "reduce" : 0,
            "output" : 1
        },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, just like your question has two parts, I could think of two separate solution, however I don't see a way to join them together.

For first part $where can be used to do a reverse regex, but it's dirty, it's an overkill and it can't use any indexes, since $where runs on each documents.

```
db.TypeCategory.find({$where:function(){for(var i  in this.maincategories)
{for(var j in this.maincategories[i].subcategories)
 {if("AFG101".indexOf(this.maincategories[i].subcategories[j].code)>=0)
  {return true}}}}},{"maincategories.subcategories.code":1})
```

Even if you use this option, it would need couple of boundary check and it cannot project two level of nested array. MongoDB doesn't support such projection (yet).

For that purpose we might go for aggregation

```
db.TypeCategory.aggregate([{$unwind:"$maincategories"},
 {$unwind:"$maincategories.subcategories"},
 {$match:{"maincategories.subcategories.code":"AFG"}},
 {$group:{_id:"$_id","maincategories":{$push:"$maincategories"}}}
])
```

However I don't think there is a way to do reverse regex check in aggregation, but I might be wrong too. Also this aggregation is costly since there are two unwinds which can lead to overflow the memory limit for aggregation for a really large collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $substr and do it

```
db.getCollection('cat').aggregate([
          {"$unwind" : "$maincategories"},
          {"$unwind" : "$maincategories.subcategories"},
          {"$project" :
                {"maincategories" : 1,
                "title":1,"sub" : {"$substr" :["$maincategories.subcategories.code",0,3]}}},
         {"$match" : {"sub" : "AFG"}},
         {"$project" : 
                 {"maincategories" : 1,
                  "title":1}
          }
    ])
```

Comment: You can use  $group  : {"_id" : "$_id"}stage and $push to make array